# How do I display the Y axis on top of the X?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am making a application that will show the results of a case study in a tornado chart. In the tornado chart I want to show all of the positive results (display in green) on the top of all the negative results (display in red) instead of the negative and positive results being on the same level. Here is my [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/9tVwt/1/). I figured out by the [highcharts documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#colors) that  I can change the colors by doing:

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
 colors: ['#FF0000', '#00FF00']
});
```

I have not been able to find anything on how to show the Y axis over top of the X.

***EDITED***
Here is an example of what I want to accomplish

[image]

Comment: What do you mean "Y axis over the top of the X"?

Comment: @wergeld I added a photo for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try by specifying the x in negative coordinates, e.g.:

```
data: [[-21,-1746181], [-20,-1884428],[-19,-2089758], [-18,-2222362], [-17,-2537431], [-16,-2507081], [-15,-2443179],
    [-14,-2664537], [-13,-3556505], [-12,-3680231], [-11,-3143062], [-10,-2721122], [-9,-2229181], [-8,-2227768],
    [-7,-2176300], [-6,-1329968], [-5,-836804], [-4,-354784], [-3,-90569], [-2,-28367], [-1,-3878] ]
```

Demo [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Bfz2m/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can set up duplicate categores with some identifier as well as add empty `null` points for the series that does not use them or put `[x,y]` points to show which category index it should go to. Then you need to modify your labels to remove the identifier.
New categories:

```
categories = ['0-4', '5-9', '10-14', '15-19',
    '20-24', '25-29', '30-34', '35-39', '40-44',
    '45-49', '50-54', '55-59', '60-64', '65-69',
    '70-74', '75-79', '80-84', '85-89', '90-94',
    '95-99', '100 +',
    'a0-4', 'a5-9', 'a10-14', 'a15-19',
    'a20-24', 'a25-29', 'a30-34', 'a35-39', 'a40-44',
    'a45-49', 'a50-54', 'a55-59', 'a60-64', 'a65-69',
    'a70-74', 'a75-79', 'a80-84', 'a85-89', 'a90-94',
    'a95-99', 'a100 +'];
```

New data series:

```
    series: [{
        name: 'Male',
        data: [-1746181, -1884428, -2089758, -2222362, -2537431, -2507081, -2443179, -2664537, -3556505, -3680231, -3143062, -2721122, -2229181, -2227768, -2176300, -1329968, -836804, -354784, -90569, -28367, -3878,
        null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
        null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
        null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
    }, {
        name: 'Female',
        data: [null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
        null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
        null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
        1656154, 1787564, 1981671, 2108575, 2403438, 2366003, 2301402, 2519874,
        3360596, 3493473, 3050775, 2759560, 2304444, 2426504, 2568938, 1785638,
        1447162, 1005011, 330870, 130632, 21208]
    }]
```

New `xAxis.label.formatter` (needed on both xAxis):

```
            formatter: function () {
                var text = this.value;
                if (text.charAt(0) == "a") {
                    return text.substring(1);;
                } else {
                    return text;
                }
            }
```

You will  need a similar thing on the `tooltip`:

```
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            var text = this.point.category;
                if (text.charAt(0) == "a") {
                    text = text.substring(1);;
                } else {
                    text = text;
                }
            return '<b>' + this.series.name + ', age ' + text + '</b><br/>' +
                'Population: ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(Math.abs(this.point.y), 0);
        }
    }
```

Live [**demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/9tVwt/4/).

Comment: This actually answers a question I had about changing out the X and Y 'tick' labels for text. This will make it much easier!